# why loadFromFile produces access violation when reading location?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am new to c ++ / SFML and I don't know why my program cannot load a texture, I tried putting the image in my project folder and in the debug folder but it didn't work.

Code:

```
int main() {
sf::RenderWindow window(VideoMode(600,600),"Window");

sf::Event event;

sf::Texture textura;
textura.loadFromFile("icono.png");

sf::Sprite sprite1(textura);

while (window.isOpen()) {
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type== sf::Event::EventType::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite1);
    window.display();
}
```

}

The error is "Unhandled exception at 0x5F6D3647 (vcruntime140.dll) in TestSFML.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading location 0x00701000" in the line "textura.loadFromFile("icono.png");"

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and share it in case it helps. The possible solution is to add the SFML debug libraries in "additional dependencies", the libraries are "sfml-graphics-d.lib" and "sfml-system-d.lib".